# Problem while Displaying the details in table

Tags: javascript

I'm making simple JavaScript program and I have to take five personal details from a user like name, address, city, gender and age. These details I've to show in table format but the program isn't working.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementbyId("btn");
btn1.addEventListener("click", details);
var row = 1;

function details() {
  var name = document.getElementbyId("name").value;
  var address = document.getElementbyId("address").value;
  var city = document.getElementbyId("city").value;
  var age = document.getElementbyId("age").value;
  var gender = document.getElementbyId("gender").value;

  var table = document.getElementbyId("display");

  var newrow = table.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newrow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newrow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newrow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newrow.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = newrow.insertCell(4);

  cell1.innerHtml = name;
  cell2.innerHtml = address;
  cell3.innerHtml = city;
  cell4.innerHtml = age;
  cell5.innerHtml = gender;

  row++;
}
```

```html
<div>
  name: <input type="text" name="n1" id="name"><br><br> address: <input type="text" name="a" id="address"><br><br> city: <input type="text" name="c1" id="city"><br><br> age: <input type="text" name="a1" id="age"><br><br> gender: <input type="text" name="g1"
    id="gender"><br><br>
  <button id="btn">submit</button><br><br>
</div>
<table id="display" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>gender</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Typos in your `getElementbyId `

Comment: `getElementById` instead of getElementbyId and `innerHTML` instead of innerHtml

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.  You need to use `document.getElementById` and `innerHTML` instead of `innerHtml`:

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn");
btn1.addEventListener("click", details);
var row = 1;

function details() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("display");

  var newrow = table.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newrow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newrow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newrow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newrow.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = newrow.insertCell(4);

  cell1.innerHTML = name;
  cell2.innerHTML = address;
  cell3.innerHTML = city;
  cell4.innerHTML = age;
  cell5.innerHTML = gender;

  row++;
}
```

```html
<div>
  name: <input type="text" name="n1" id="name"><br><br> address: <input type="text" name="a" id="address"><br><br> city: <input type="text" name="c1" id="city"><br><br> age: <input type="text" name="a1" id="age"><br><br> gender: <input type="text" name="g1"
    id="gender"><br><br>
  <button id="btn">submit</button><br><br>
</div>
<table id="display" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>gender</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much but will you tell me what is typos

Comment: @Shivamsingh In this case, mistakes in your code.

Comment: "typos" is short for "type setting mistakes". Coming from a special kind of mistake caused by the person doing the selection of lead print characters (as opposed to technical mistakes, grammar, ... which the author usually makes).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
  name: <input type="text" name="n1" id="name"><br><br> address: <input type="text" name="a" id="address"><br><br> city: <input type="text" name="c1" id="city"><br><br> age: <input type="text" name="a1" id="age"><br><br> gender: <input type="text" name="g1"
    id="gender"><br><br>
  <button id="btn">submit</button><br><br>
</div>
<table id="display" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>gender</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("display");

  var newrow = table.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newrow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newrow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newrow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newrow.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = newrow.insertCell(4);

  cell1.innerHTML  = name;
  cell2.innerHTML  = address;
  cell3.innerHTML  = city;
  cell4.innerHTML  = age;
  cell5.innerHTML  = gender;

  row++;
});

var row = 1;


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied and paste your code in my editor to test then. Please, two things that you need to pear attention:

1-JavaScript syntax aspects: The JavaScript is a *Case Sensitive* language, if you write some code that use native functions and objects, its mandatory to write your code following the correct syntax;

2-Your approach needs to right the syntax (mentioned before) and change the `innerHtml` to `innerText` for populate your table.

Bellow, I add code with all changes that need:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn");
btn1.addEventListener("click", details);
var row = 1;

function details() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("display");

  var newrow = table.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newrow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newrow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newrow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newrow.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = newrow.insertCell(4);

  cell1.innerText = name;
  cell2.innerText = address;
  cell3.innerText = city;
  cell4.innerText = age;
  cell5.innerText = gender;

  row++;
}
```